# Oracle JNDI Tomcat and Spring

Tags: oracle, spring, tomcat, jndi

I'm trying to configure an Oracle JNDI DataSource in Tomcat to use with my Spring DataSource, but I am having a problem every time I try to connect to my Database.

Here is my configuration:

In my app /META-INF/context.xml

```
<Context docBase="web-site" path="/web-site" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:web-site">

    <Resource name="jdbc/OracleDB" auth="Container"
    type="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" username="system" password="xxxxx"
    driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:XE"
    factory="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSourceFactory" maxactive="40"
    maxidle="3" maxwait="10000" poolpreparedstatements="true"
    maxopenpreparedstatements="100" validationquery="SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL" />

</Context>
```

In WEB-INF/web.xml:

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>Oracle Connection Pool</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/OracleDB</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

In spring-dao-config.xml:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/OracleDB" />
    <property name="resourceRef" value="true"/>
    <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.sql.DataSource" />
    <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="true" />
</bean>
```

When i try to run my app, I have this error page:

```
    org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
cause mère

org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:440)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:335)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    $Proxy18.readAll(Unknown Source)
    com.website.controller.HelloWorldController.helloWord(HelloWorldController.java:20)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
cause mère

org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:52)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:304)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:169)
    org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
    org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1263)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:399)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:335)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    $Proxy18.readAll(Unknown Source)
    com.website.controller.HelloWorldController.helloWord(HelloWorldController.java:20)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
cause mère

java.sql.SQLException: arguments non valides dans l'appel
    oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:113)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:147)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:209)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:236)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:454)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:802)
    oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleDataSource.java:298)
    oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:222)
    oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:166)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:196)
    $Proxy6.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:141)
    org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:276)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:297)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:169)
    org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
    org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1263)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:399)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:335)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    $Proxy18.readAll(Unknown Source)
    com.website.controller.HelloWorldController.helloWord(HelloWorldController.java:20)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

Have you any idea about my problem please?
Thank you

Comment: You should remove the "path" and "docBase" attributes from your META-INF/context.xml file. Maybe those are put in by NetBeans, but they should not be in there.

Comment: Yes I deleted the attributes but nothing happened, same behavior

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original exception is "java.sql.SQLException: arguments non valides dans l'appel" (in English: "java.sql.SQLException: invalid arguments in call") and is occurring at the driver level. I don't believe this is a problem in Tomcat.

I would check your Oracle JDBC URL ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:XE") to make sure that it is accurate, appropriate for the driver that you are using (are you using the thin driver? most people do, but it's worth checking), and correctly formatted.

If you continue to have trouble, consider using Tomcat's built-in DataSource (just remove the "factory" attribute from your <Resource> element)... you may have better luck.

Comment: Thank you Christopher, I tried to do what you suggest and I have no problem now!!

Comment: Here my context.xml
    <Resource name="jdbc/OracleDB" auth="Container"
  type="javax.sql.DataSource" username="system" password="xxxxxx"
  driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:XE"
  maxactive="40" maxidle="3" maxwait="10000" poolpreparedstatements="true"
  maxopenpreparedstatements="100" validationquery="SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL" />

I changed also the type to : type="javax.sql.DataSource"

Comment: I hadn't noticed the "type" attribute originally: I suspect that has had more impact than you changing the connection pool. Try going back to Oracle's pool and leaving "type" as "javax.sql.DataSource".

Comment: There are an error: Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: JNDI object with [java:comp/env/jdbc/OracleDB] not found: JNDI implementation returned null

Answer (score 1):

Could see only 1 issue, shouldn't the res-type in your web.xml file be `javax.sql.DataSource`

```
 <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
```